# Не получается организовать вывод данных

Tags: c++, классы

У меня есть класс лампочек lamp. Мне нужно вывести с помощью метода TEST() всю информацию, про лампы накаливания (они обозначены как n). 
Для этого я создал метод gettype(), который должен получать информацию о типе лампочки, и метод тест, который должен выводить информацию о лампочке. Я пытаюсь посмотреть все экземпляры класса и, как уже написал выше, вывести информацию про те, которые лампы накаливания. Получаю кучу синтаксических ошибок, с которыми ничего не могу сделать. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Ошибки:

[image: Ошибки]

Строки:

```
7 и 8 --->>> if (lamp[i].gettype == "n") {

8, 9, 10, 11 --->>> lamp[i].TEST();
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class lamp 
{
public:
    //методы
    void TEST(void);
    char* gettype (void);
    void INIT(void);
    void SHOW(void);
    //конструкторы  
    lamp();
    lamp(char *t, int powe, char *c, double cos);
    lamp(const lamp & obj);
    //деструктор
    ~lamp();
private:
    //данные
    char type[100]; // светодиодная, энергосберегающая или лампа накаливания 
    int power;      // ЛАМПА НАКАЛИВАНИЯ - "n"
    char color[100];
    double cost;
};

lamp::lamp() {
    cout << "Этот обьект был создан в конструкторе по умолчанию.\n";
    strcpy(type, "");
    power = 0;
    strcpy(color, "");
    cost = 0;
}

lamp::lamp(char *t, int powe, char *c, double cos) {
    cout << "Этот обьект был создан в конструкторе с параметрами.\n";
    strcpy(type, t); //*t
    power = powe;
    strcpy(color, c); //*c
    cost = cos;
}

lamp::lamp(const lamp & obj) {
    cout << "Этот обьект был создан в конструкторе копирования.\n";
    strcpy(type, obj.type);
    power = obj.power;
    strcpy(color, obj.color);
    cost = obj.cost;
}

lamp::~lamp() {
    cout << "Удаление объекта деструктором.\n";
}

void lamp::SHOW(void) {
    cout << "Информация о лампе:\n";
    cout << "\nТип > " << type;
    cout << "\nМощность > " << power;
    cout << "\nЦвет > " << color;
    cout << "\nСтоимость > " << cost << endl;
}

void lamp::INIT(void) {
    cout << "Введите данные о лампе:\n";
    cout << "\nТип (если накаливания, то n) > "; cin >> type;
    cout << "\nМощность > "; cin >> power;
    cout << "\nЦвет > "; cin >> color;
    cout << "\nСтоимость > "; cin >> cost;
}

char* lamp::gettype (void) {
    return type;
}

void lamp::TEST(void) {
    cout << "\nТип > " << type;
    cout << "\nМощность > " << power;
    cout << "\nЦвет > " << color;
    cout << "\nСтоимость > " << cost << endl;
}

void main() {
    setlocale(0, "");

    // конструктор по умолчанию для 1 экземпляра класса
    lamp l1;
    cout << "Введение данных для первого товара." << endl;
    l1.INIT();

    // конструктор с параметрами для 2 экземпляра класса
    cout << endl << "Информация про второй объект: \n"; 
    lamp l2("накаливания", 950, "желтый", 1580);

    // конструктор копирования для третьего объекта
    cout << endl << "Информация про третий объект: \n";
    lamp l3(l2);

    // вывел информацию про все лампы с помощью метода SHOW
    l1.SHOW();
    l2.SHOW();
    l3.SHOW();

    // создаю массив из двух объектов с помощью конструктора по умолчанию
    lamp la[2];
        // ввожу данные в массив объектов с помощью метода INIT
    cout << "Заполним массив объектов из 2 элементов." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        la[i].INIT();
    }
        // вывожу данные из массива объектов с помощью метода SHOW
    cout << "Показываю элементы." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        la[i].SHOW();
    }

    // ищу и вывожу информацию про лампы, с типом накаливания
    cout << "Поиск и вывод информации с типом накаливания." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < lamp.size; i++) {
        if (lamp[i].gettype == "n") {
            cout << endl << " номер лампы : " << (i + 1) << endl;
            lamp[i].TEST();
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или в последнем цикле у Вас вместо **lamp[i]** должно быть **la[i]**? И **gettype** у Вас вроде как функция? Тогда где круглые скобки? И кстати, поля **size** в вашем классе я тоже не вижу....

Comment: (lamp[i].gettype() == "n") вы забыли круглые скобочки для вызова. Компилятор явно указывает на ошибки, к чему такие вопросы?     Лучше  спросили бы как логически правильно представлять лампочку, а то у вас получается та: если :   есть возможность ввести любую строку для инициализации вида лампочки и цвета, и есть возможность ввести любую цифру, для инициализации мощности.  И  где вы видели, чтобы лампочка выдавала о себе информации? Это же  просто простая лампочка...

Answer (score 4):

Никогда не проверяйте С-строки (`char*`), просто используя `==` - это вы сравниваете два указателя, и не более того...

Далее, `void main()`... уже много лет стандарт **требует** писать `int main()`.

Еще - пожалуйста, приучите себя использовать `const`. Вот вы пишете

```
lamp(char *t, ...
```

Значит ли это, что ваш конструктор будет изменять переданную ему строку? Нет? Вы просто ее копируете? А откуда же об этом знать компилятору, раз вы не написали `const`? А менять *литералы* нельзя, вы не можете неявно привести `"Hello"` к указателю на `char` - только к указателю на `const char`. Меняйте все эти

```
lamp(char *t, ...
```

на

```
lamp(const char *t, ...
```

Вот тут

```
for (int i = 0; i < lamp.size; i++) {
```

совсем непонятно. Никакого `size` в вашем классе `lamp` нет, да и обращение `lamp.size` неправильное - ведь `lamp` - это класс, тип, но не объект! Тут надо всерьез переписывать и разбираться вам, это не синтаксическая ошибка...

То же самое и здесь -

```
lamp[i].gettype
```

непонятное обращение - через имя класса, как к массиву, обращение к функции без `()`...

Знаете, какое ощущение? Вы взяли чужой код, не думая, что-то поменяли, и теперь надеетесь последовательными вопросами здесь на сайте довести его до ума, раз уж тут не делают полностью домашку за других... Очень *неприятное* ощущение.